# The attachments is empty in mailmessageattachments

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql

When I execute the query as shown the attachment is always empty. I would expect that the contents of the attachment with name `AttachmentFileName` would be in the column `Attachment`.

How do I retrieve the blob of the file?

```
select /*+ join_set(mat, mailmessageid, 5000) */ mat.Attachment xmlfilecontents
,      mat.division || '-' || AttachmentFileName filename
from   mailmessagesreceived mre
join   MailMessageAttachments mat
on     mat.mailmessageid = mre.id
and    mat.Type in ( 20, 22 ) /* 20: UBL 2.0, 22: Simplerinvoicing 1.0 */
where  mre.SenderMailbox = 'Facturen@ExactOnline.nl'
and    mre.created >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, -1), -10)
and    mat.FileSize > 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column `Attachment` stores the attachment directly associated with the received Exact Online `MailMessage`, as long as the mail message hasn't been processed. In that case, the attachment is forwarded to `Documents`.

However, the Exact Online invoices itself are retrieved indirectly. The Internet location is in the field `Url`. It is also available in the table using the column `AttachmentFromUrl`.